# Validación de enteros y decimales

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Me gustaría que me orienten de como validar números enteros y decimales con `jQuery`.

Hola, estoy validando enteros con esta función.

```
$(function () {
            $('.enteros').on('input', function () {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            });
        });


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="enteros" type=text />
```

Pero aun no puedo validar decimales (utilizando coma como separador)

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con Javascript puro, sin complicarte con librerías de terceros. Pero, una pregunta: ¿cómo sería el tipo de validación que quieres? ¿Quieres que te evalúe como entero tanto esto: `"12"`, como esto: `12`  y como decimal tanto esto: `"4.5"` como esto `4.5`? ¿O solamente los datos que sean estrictamente números, sin comillas, los cuales deberá decirte que son una cadena?

Comment: Relacionado [Como validar un input solo puedan entrar decimales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/257977/65)

Answer (score 6):

- Para saber **si es un número entero**, podrías usar [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

```js
console.log(Number.isInteger(5));
console.log(Number.isInteger("5"));
console.log(Number.isInteger(5.2));
console.log(Number.isInteger(Infinity));
```

- Para saber si **es un número con decimales**, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
Number.isFloat = Number.isFloat || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && 
    isFinite(value) &&
    Math.floor(value) !== value;
};

console.log(Number.isFloat(5));
console.log(Number.isFloat("5"));
console.log(Number.isFloat(5.2));
console.log(Number.isFloat(Infinity));
```

--- UPDATE ---

- Para validar si **es un número con coma como separador decimal**, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
function isCommaDecimalNumber(value) {
  return /^-?(?:\d+(?:,\d*)?)$/.test(value);
}

console.log(5, isCommaDecimalNumber(5));
console.log("'5'", isCommaDecimalNumber('5'));
console.log(5.2, isCommaDecimalNumber(5.2));
console.log("'5,'", isCommaDecimalNumber('5,'));
console.log("'5,2'", isCommaDecimalNumber('5,2'));
console.log("'-'", isCommaDecimalNumber('-'));
console.log("'-5'", isCommaDecimalNumber('-5'));
console.log("'5,2'", isCommaDecimalNumber('-5,2'));
```

Comment: Al realizar, Number.isFloat || function() verificas si la función estaba previamente implementada ?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, si, esto normalmente se hace cuando se extienden objetos nativos. Puede que el día de mañana este método que sean implementados por los distintos navegadores.

Comment: No conocia esos metodos. Muy buena respuesta. Asi te ahorras hacer funciones de mas.

Comment: El autor de la pregunta la modificó para indicar que usa coma como separador de decimales. Quizás quieras agregar algo al respecto a tu respuesta.

Comment: @Rubén, gracias por la observación. He actualizado mi respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 5):

Comprueba el resto al dividir por 1:

```js
console.log("Es entero: "+isInt(1));
console.log("Es entero: "+isInt(1.5));

function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Si no sabes si el argumento es un número, necesitas dos condiciones:

```js
console.log("Es entero: "+isInt(1));
console.log("Es entero: "+isInt(1.5));
console.log("Es decimal: "+isFloat(1));
console.log("Es decimal: "+isFloat(1.5));

function isInt(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
}

function isFloat(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}
```

Fuente: [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo calculando el modulo 1 del dato.

```
var numero=1.3;
if(numero % 1 !=0){
    console.log("Es decimal");
}else{
    console.log("Es entero");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función es la más corta y hará el trabajo completamente.

```js
var type = e => typeof e === 'number' && e%1 === 0 && isFinite(e) ? 'Integer' : typeof e === 'number' && e%1 !== 0 && isFinite(e) ? 'Float' : 'Is not a number';
```

Answer (score 0):

Como estás usando un `<input type="text">` para recibir como entrada un número ya sea entero o decimal puedes usar usar el atributo `pattern` para señalar con la pseudo-clase `invalid`si el valor capturado no es un número entero ni decimales con lo cual no requieres usar jQuery, ni siquiera JavaScript.

```css
input:invalid{
 background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^\d*,?\d*$">
```

jQuery o JavaScript serían necesarios para hacer alguna acción determinada, como mostrar un mensaje personalizado o inhabilitar/habilitar un botón, otros campos, etc.

Referencia

- [Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12117024/1595451)