# Como validar un input solo puedan entrar decimales

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-validate

tengo el siguiente problema, en un campo input solo se pueden entrar numeros decimales con dos numeros despues del punto.

ejemplo 5.25 o 132.50

he intentado con lo siguiente por no he resuelto:

```
    function ValidateMoney(_id) {
    var amount = document.getElementById(_id).value;
    var patron = /^(\d+|\d+.\d{2})$/;
    if (!patron.test(amount)) {
        window.alert('cantidad ingresada incorrectamente');
        document.getElementById('amount').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Este es mi html

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="requiredcomponent">Amount</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control" name="price" data-field="Amount" min="0" step="0.05" title="Amount" id="amount">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cual debería ser el separado decimal, el punto (`.`) o la coma (`,`)? Pregunto porque en la [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) usas coma, pero en los números de ejemplo usas punto.

Comment: ¿Que elemento es el que tiene id 'amount' y al que intentas hacer focus?

Comment: Tienes mal el regexp en todo caso, debes separar en dos grupos para usar el `|`. Aclara el tema de los decimales también, ¿es punto o es coma?

Comment: disculpen el error, es con punto el separador, pero no me funciona para dos decimales despues del punto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te dije en mi comentario, el problema es la forma en la que usas el operador lógico `|`, ya que el mismo (como lo tienes) actúa sólo sobre un grupo de búsqueda, y a ti te interesa tener 2 grupos diferenciados.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea validar un campo `input` de HTML, usando Javascript, de tal manera que solo permita hasta 2 decimales en cantidades numéricas. El separador para decimales es `.`

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar dicha validación usaremos una expresión regular y compararemos el valor del elemento `input` contra dicha expresión regular.

La dificultad solo radica en que debemos detectar cuando la cantidad lleva decimales y cuando no los lleva.

Una expresión regular puede componerse de grupos de búsqueda que se encierran entre paréntesis. Podemos establecer un grupo de búsqueda para hacer `match` con números que no llevan cantidad decimal y otro grupo de búsqueda para números que si llevan valore decimal.

Una forma de realizar la validación sería la siguiente:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('button');
const isValid = /^(\d+)$|^(\d+\.{1}\d{2})$/;
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
  if (!isValid.test(cantidad)) {
    alert('Formato no válido')
  } else {
    console.log('Validación superada: ', cantidad);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholder="00.00"><br>
  <button type="button" id="button">Validar</button>
 </div>
```

En nuestra [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp), tenemos los siguientes grupos:

1. `^(\d+)$`: Indica dígitos que pueden repetirse. Se debe iniciar con dígitos (`^`) y se debe finalizar con dígitos (`$`).
2. `|`: Operador lógico tipo `OR`.
3. `^(\d+\.{1}\d{2})$`: El segundo grupo de búsqueda que actúa sobre números con decimales. Indica que el patrón ha de empezar con dígitos, debe contener exactamente 1 punto y ha de terminar con exactamente 2 dígitos.

Espero que sea la validación que estabas buscando.

Comment: En efecto era eso mismo Mauricio, Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score -1):

solo debes hacer una pequeña modificación en tu expresión. Agrega paréntesis a la evaluación de decimales y ponlo como opcional (?), ya que puede ser valido un numero entero también. Por ejemplo: 5 es válido, 5.00 también es válido.

```html
    <label class="requiredcomponent">Amount</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0" step="0.05" id="amount" onchange="ValidateMoney('amount')">

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function ValidateMoney(_id)
     {
      var amount = document.getElementById(_id).value;
      console.log(amount);
                   //d+ permite caracteres enteros
                   //si hay un caracter que no es dígito entonces evalua lo que está en paréntesis (?) significa opcional
      var patron = /^(\d+(.{1}\d{2})?)$/;           
                    if (!patron.test(amount))
      {
          window.alert('cantidad ingresada incorrectamente');
          document.getElementById('amount').focus();
          return false;
        }
      else
          return true;
    }
 </script>
```